Rewrite nginx to htaccess
In a nutshell, I have this working nginx rewrite rule:
rewrite ^/stire-(.*)$ /stire.php?url=https://$1;
and I'm trying to port it to Apache. I've tried lots of RewriteRule combinations in the htaccess file, none of them worked. Any ideas please?
The purpose is to change stire.php?url=https://whateverelse into stire-whateverelse.
RewriteRule ^stire.\/php\?=https\:\/\/?(.*)$ "https:\/\/site\.org\/stire-$1" [R=301,L] 
this is the last, nothing worked.

Another one that (from my knowledge) should work RewriteRule ^stire-(.*)$ /stire.php?url=https://$1   atill another 404 error page

Your question is a bit vague, but this probably is what you are looKing for:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?stire- /stire.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

If the url parameter should not receive a full URL as your question suggests, but only what follow the "stire-" prefix, then that variant should get you started:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?stire-(.+)$ /stire.php?url=$1 [L]

This rules works likewise in the central http server's host configuration (that should be preferred) or, if you do not have access to that, in a distributed configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"). In the latter case you need to take care to store that file in the folder marked as DocumentRoot for the http host, the file needs to be readable by the http server process and you need to enable the interpretation of such commands on a per-directory-base by means of the AllowOverride directive in the central configuration (check the documentation for details on that).
